# Variable <title> for FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

FOSUserBundle and its derivatives (e.g., PUGXMultiUserBundle) do not provide for variable title tags in the html header.  Instead, a fixed title tag is suggested in the documentation.

An answer to this (minor) problem is provided below.

#### layout.html.twig

```
...
<title>{% include "AcmeDemoBundle:Default:title.html.twig" %}</title>
...
```

#### title.html.twig

```
{% if title is defined %}
    {{ title }}
{% else %}
    {% set path = app.request.pathinfo|split('/') %}
    {{ path.1|title }} {% if path.2 is defined %}{{ path.2|title }}{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

#### Examples:

For PUGXMultiUserBundle's `/register/staff` path the title is `Register Staff`
For FOSUserBundle's `/login` path the title is `Login`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### layout.html.twig

```
...
<title>{% include "AcmeDemoBundle:Default:title.html.twig" %}</title>
...
```

#### title.html.twig

```
{% if title is defined %}
    {{ title }}
{% else %}
    {% set path = app.request.pathinfo|split('/') %}
    {{ path.1|title }} {% if path.2 is defined %}{{ path.2|title }}{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

#### Examples:

For PUGXMultiUserBundle's `/register/staff` path the title is `Register Staff`
For FOSUserBundle's `/login` path the title is `Login`